# silverlight 4 not work in firefox and chrome

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I create Silverlight WCF RIA application. I use Entity Framework 4 for data access.

I test my application on IE 8 and it work fine but when I test on Firefox 4 or Chrome 10 I got Exception when I call RIA service. (It got error even service that just return data)

I want to know, how can I make Silverlight 4 application work on IE, Firefox and Chrome?

**Error:**

```
-- Exception -->
Load operation failed for query 'GetData'. Exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainOperationException' was thrown.

-- stack -->
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.WebDomainClient`1.EndQueryCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainClient.EndQuery(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.CompleteLoad(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

Comment: I just added error message and it stack trace.

Comment: I dont think it has any issue whether its firefox or chrome, we have RIA services working fine, mostly it will be because of wrong URL and some characters in it, in how you are launching your browser and its page.

Comment: I had deployed application to our server and when user use it in IE it work properly but when they switch to Firefox or Chrome, they got this error when they work on same feature. Anyway I got this error from logging mechanism in our application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can remember. This is a bug on Silverlight runtime. We called Microsoft for this case and they also said it is a bug and no more response. We decided to drop the support on Firefox and go only with IE.